# Tracking the user's last activity

Tags: mysql

I have a table setup for member logins. Right now the `last_login` field is stamped with `MySQL's NOW()`. But I want to also track their last active time on the site. And the only way I can think of is to create a *new query*, insert it into every procedure I have on every page, and update a timestamped `last_activity` field for the current login. Is there a better way to do this?

Example:

```
MariaDB [master]> select logintime, last_activity
                  from memberlogins 
                  where memberid = "1" 
                  order by loginid  
                  desc limit 1;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| logintime           | last_activity       |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2017-02-11 22:28:54 | 2017-02-11 23:48:14 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

That's what I want, to add the last_activity to the table. And the only way I can think of to accomplish this is to add this query:

```
$stmt = $dbsotp->prepare('UPDATE memberlogins
                          SET last_activity = NOW()
                          WHERE memberid = :memberid');
```

And then the rest of the PDO here. So all I'm asking is if there's a better way to do this than inserting this query into every procedure I have on every page. I have 67 pages with a several hundred procedures, that's why I ask if this is the only way or if there's a better way to go.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You can setup a common file to be executed before the requested page.

Comment: "last activity" could denote a lot of things. "Last activity" could refer to the last time they switched pages or the last time a key was pressed or the last time the mouse was moved or the last time the mouse was clicked.

Comment: @Icemanind - that's all I want. Just to see if they have life in them or not. It doesn't matter what they're doing, I just want to see if they're doing something. Anything.

Comment: @faintsignal - but what if they're doing a lot of work on the same page? Having the common file execute at page load time wldn't provide me with activity updates, right?

Comment: @Landslyde Right, that strategy would be suitable for actions occurring at page request time that are expected to execute quickly. If client makes AJAX (e.g.) calls, you could handle it in a wrapper function on the server. Another strategy, say if you want virtually every INSERT/UPDATE to be accompanied by a `last_activity` field update, is to wrap your database calls in a function that updates the user record as a side-effect — or maybe you're able to have something more slick that just updates this field after everything else is done. It depends on the structure of your app and its needs.

Comment: @faintsignal - Thanks for your input. I wish I'd thought of tracking this 67 pages ago :-)

Comment: You might also want to look into database triggers.

Comment: @faintsignal - I've never worked with triggers. This may be a good time to start. Thanks again for your help.